# How to determine the module name to filter a specific Python warning?

Tags: python, command-line, warnings

With Python one can [filter specific warnings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warning-filter) using the following command line syntax:

```
-W action:message:category:module:line
```

But how can one determine the correct value for `module` for a particular warning?

Consider the following example:

Using (`pipenv --python 3.6.5 install lxml==4.2.4`)

```
> python -W error -c "from lxml import etree"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 75, in init lxml.etree
  File "src/lxml/_elementpath.py", line 56, in init lxml._elementpath
ImportWarning: can't resolve package from __spec__ or __package__, falling back on __name__ and __path__
```

If one wanted to ignore only that specific import warning, how does one find the module name to use? None of the following commands appear to be correct. They all still emit the warning.

```
python -W error -W ignore::ImportWarning:lxml -c "from lxml import etree"
python -W error -W ignore::ImportWarning:lxml.etree -c "from lxml import etree"
python -W error -W ignore::ImportWarning:lxml._elementpath -c "from lxml import etree"
python -W error -W ignore::ImportWarning:etree -c "from lxml import etree"
python -W error -W ignore::ImportWarning:_elementpath -c "from lxml import etree"
python -W error -W 'ignore::ImportWarning:lxml[.*]' -c "from lxml import etree"
```

Comment: Which Python version are you using? For me (Win7, Py3.4) there is no warning.

Comment: Hm, probably because I have `lxml`?

Comment: It's in the pipenv command in the question. If you have pipenv you can run it with the exact version of lxml too. Though really I'm interested in a general method to determine a module name rather than just for this case. Thanks.

Comment: As I read [Python 3.7.0 Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html) there should **NO** space between `-W` and `ignore`. Example for your case [describing-warning-filters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#describing-warning-filters)

Comment: @stovfl, I believe whitespace between the flag and the value is optional. You can verify that the following works (though it ignores *all* import warnings): `python -W error -W ignore::ImportWarning -c "from lxml import etree"`

Comment: Tested, does not work for me, either with or without whitespace. Realized differences in the docs. My above Link **describing-warning-filters** does not exist in my Python 3.5.

Comment: Start with setting all warnings to *exceptions* so you can trace the location that creates the warning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the `ImportWarning` warnings, in fact, is from [import.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.1/Python/import.c#L1538-L1540), but you need to filter with `_frozen_importlib`, the stacks in the warning message are incomplete and internal stacks are omitted. you could obtain this info by overridden `warnings.showwarning`:

```
import warnings

def showwarning(message, category, filename, lineno, file, line):
    print(filename)

warnings.showwarning = showwarning
warnings.resetwarnings() # allow all warnings

from lxml import etree
```

you could verify this by:

```
python -Werror::ImportWarning:_frozen_importlib -c 'import lxml.etree'
```

btw `ImportWarning` is [ignored by default](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.1/Lib/warnings.py#L551).

Comment: For anyone coming here with warnings raised via `runpy` aka `python -m somemodule` calls (e.g., `torch.distributed.launch`), the way to ignore them looks like e.g. `ignore::FutureWarning:__main__:178`. Notice `__main__` where you would assume `somemodule` should be.